# Table with empty rows until populated

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to show a table with 10 empty rows. The user then can start entering data from the first row (the data will be inserted/updated in a mongo collection), once the 10th row is populated another empty row should be added to the end of the table and so on. The table should maintain 10 row view and will be scroll-able.

Is there a simple way to do it in meteor?

Comment: I Built a <table> element hard coded, but I have no Idea how to do what I wrote in my question

Comment: I need some direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you would like to store this data in a collection, so you should start my making one of those:

`CollName = new Meteor.Collection('collName');`

Then i would insert to 10 blank items for whatever fields you want to capture (i.e.

```js
[{
  "name": "",
  "comment": "",
  "something": ""
}, {
  "name": "",
  "comment": "",
  "something": ""
}, ....
 {
  "name": "",
  "comment": "",
  "something": ""
}]
```

And then iterate over them in the template:

```html
{{#each collItems}}
<tr>
  <td>{{name}}</td>
  <td>{{comment}}</td>
  <td>{{something}}</td>
</tr>
((/each}}
```

If you want to only show 10 at a time, you could set the `limit` to 10 in the template helper / find query.

This should put you in the right direction, but I'd suggest looking at packages like [autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform) and [simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) on Atmosphere.

Comment: tnx! this helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for a table with 10 empty rows. You are looking for a table with 10 rows with input fields